# ImageView not showing full size in LinearLayout

Tags: android-layout

For fun I am working on the Udacity Popular Movies app.  I'm at the point where I'm clicking the movie image in the GridView and going to the detail view where i'm hoping to display the backdrop image on top, title below that, and overview below that.  All in LinearLayout with the gravity for everything at the top.

[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbooA.jpg)

[Detail Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrrh9.jpg)

Here is the code to set the image in the ImageView:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movie.backDrop).into(imageView);
```

Here is the Detail Layout File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ferr3t.don.gurumovies.MovieDetail">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_title" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_description" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure why the image is centered and small  I want it to Fill the width of the screen.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in in xml Imageview property

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: That stretched the image across the screen, but left the height the same size.

Comment: Use centralcrop behalf of fitxy

Comment: centerCrop stretched the image accross the screen, but then cropped it so that it is the same height as fitXY.  Any another ideas?  So far the only way i can get it to work is to set the layout_height="200dp" but of course that will mess things up when it goes into landscape mode.